Rust Get Text From EDIT "CreateWindowExW"
I am using windows API to make a window that acts as a server and starts and shuts down on the port I specify in the “PORT” cell.
This code is using the windows crate (0.58.0)
The code for the “server_window” is:
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use windows::core::PCWSTR;
use windows::Win32::Foundation::{HWND, LPARAM, LRESULT, WPARAM};
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::{COLOR_WINDOW, HBRUSH};
use windows::Win32::System::LibraryLoader::GetModuleHandleW;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{CreateWindowExW, DefWindowProcW, GetWindowLongPtrW, GetWindowRect, GetWindowTextA, GWLP_ID, GWLP_USERDATA, IDC_ARROW, LoadCursorW, RegisterClassW, SetWindowLongPtrW, WM_COMMAND, WM_CREATE, WM_DESTROY, WNDCLASSW, WS_BORDER, WS_CAPTION, WS_CHILD, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_SYSMENU, WS_VISIBLE};

use crate::MainWindow;

pub struct ServerWindow {
    parent_hwnd: HWND,
    main_window: *mut MainWindow,
    stop_signal: Arc<Mutex<bool>>,
    hwnd_port_server: Option<HWND>,
}

impl ServerWindow {
    pub fn new(parent_hwnd: HWND, main_window: *mut MainWindow) -> Self {
        Self {
            parent_hwnd,
            main_window,
            stop_signal: Arc::new(Mutex::new(false)),
            hwnd_port_server: None,
        }
    }

    pub unsafe fn create(&mut self) {
        let class_name = PCWSTR::from_raw("ServerWindowClass\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _);
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(None).unwrap();

        let wc = WNDCLASSW {
            lpfnWndProc: Some(Self::server_window_proc),
            hInstance: hinstance.into(),
            lpszClassName: class_name,
            hbrBackground: HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW.0 as *mut _),
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(None, IDC_ARROW).unwrap(),
            ..Default::default()
        };
        // Register the window class
        RegisterClassW(&wc);

        let mut rect = Default::default();
        let _ = GetWindowRect(self.parent_hwnd, &mut rect);

        let server_window_x = rect.right;
        let server_window_y = rect.top;

        // Create the server window
        let hwnd_server = CreateWindowExW(
            Default::default(),
            class_name,
            PCWSTR::from_raw("Server\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
            WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE,
            server_window_x - 230,
            server_window_y + 180,
            205,
            175,
            None,
            None,
            hinstance,
            Some(self as *const _ as *mut _),
        ).expect("Failed to create server window");

        SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd_server, GWLP_USERDATA, self as *mut _ as isize);
    }

    unsafe extern "system" fn server_window_proc(hwnd: HWND, msg: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
        static mut STOP_SIGNAL: bool = false;

        match msg {
            WM_CREATE => {
                let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(None).unwrap();

                // Create "PORT:" static text
                let _ = CreateWindowExW(
                    Default::default(),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("STATIC\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("PORT:\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    10,
                    10,
                    90,
                    20,
                    hwnd,
                    None,
                    hinstance,
                    None,
                );

                // Create edit control for port input
                let hwnd_port_server = CreateWindowExW(
                    Default::default(),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("EDIT\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    PCWSTR::null(),
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                    60,
                    10,
                    130,
                    20,
                    hwnd,
                    None,
                    hinstance,
                    None,
                ).expect("Failed to create port edit control");
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd_port_server, GWLP_ID, 1);


                // Create "START" button
                let hwnd_start_button = CreateWindowExW(
                    Default::default(),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("BUTTON\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("START\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    10,
                    35,
                    180,
                    50,
                    hwnd,
                    None,
                    hinstance,
                    None,
                ).expect("Failed to create START button");
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd_start_button, GWLP_ID, 2);

                // Create "STOP" button
                let hwnd_stop_button = CreateWindowExW(
                    Default::default(),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("BUTTON\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    PCWSTR::from_raw("STOP\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr() as *mut _),
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    10,
                    90,
                    180,
                    50,
                    hwnd,
                    None,
                    hinstance,
                    None,
                ).expect("Failed to create STOP button");
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd_stop_button, GWLP_ID, 3);
                LRESULT(0)
            }
            WM_COMMAND => {
                match wparam.0 {
                    1 => {
                        println!("Prueba1")
                    }
                    2 => {
                        STOP_SIGNAL = false;
                        println!("Button START clicked");

                        // What should I do here? I need to get the port number
                    }

                    3 => { // STOP button clicked
                        println!("Servidor deteniendose...");
                        STOP_SIGNAL = true;
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
                LRESULT(0)
            }
            WM_DESTROY => {
                let main_window_ptr = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut MainWindow;
                if main_window_ptr.is_null() {
                    println!("Error: MainWindow HWND is null.");
                    return LRESULT(0);
                }

                let main_window = &mut *main_window_ptr;
                main_window.server_window_open = false;

                println!("Server window is being destroyed.");

                LRESULT(0)
            }
            _ => DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
        }
    }
}

What code should go in ID 2??
I tried this:
                        STOP_SIGNAL = false;
                        let server_window_ptr = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut ServerWindow;
                        if !server_window_ptr.is_null() {
                            let server_window = &mut *server_window_ptr;

                            // Verificar HWND de Host
                            if let Some(hwnd_port_server) = server_window.hwnd_port_server {
                                println!("HWND Host: {:?}", hwnd_port_server);
                                let mut buffer: [u16; 1024] = [0; 1024];
                                let len = GetWindowTextW(hwnd_port_server, &mut buffer);
                                if len > 0 {
                                    let port = OsString::from_wide(&buffer[..len as usize]).to_string_lossy().into_owned();
                                    println!("Host: {}", port);
                                } else {
                                    println!("Host text length is 0");
                                }
                            } else {
                                println!("Host HWND is None");
                            }
                        }
                    }

But it print "port" empty:
HWND Host: HWND(0x2a00000001)
Host text length is 0.

I don't know any other way to do it.

In this code you are not storing the hwnd_port_server anywhere, but then it has a value. Maybe there is some code missing?

If GetWindowTextW fails call GetLastError() to find out why. Unrelated to your issue, you can use the w! macro to get a PCWSTR from a string literal.

Besides, setting GWLP_ID right after creating a window (which should have set the ID already) is the kind of code you'd get out of an LLM like ChatGPT. What's up with that?
